# Why my activity restarts even I set android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" in manifest file

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest

I have 2 activities: `MainActivity` and `PdfViewActivity`. I set both of them to **`android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"`** in the manifest file. When I rotate my device, `MainActivity` doesn't restart while `PdfActivity` does even when I set `configChanges` in the manifest. Why?